# Change Textview's Text Upon Change of ComboBoxText Selection - Gtk+ 3.0 in C

Tags: c, linux, user-interface, gtk3, gtktextview

I am building a GUI program that allows users to choose between a few software profiles for them to get written to their USB drive. I have chosen GTK+ 3.0 in C, and my supervisor is aware of my chosen method, so I am not changing it.

What I am trying to do is really quite simple but I'm still having trouble finding a comprehensive answer.

I want to be able to allow the user to select a (text) entry in the combo box and have the corresponding description show up in the frame/textview. The description in the textview should change properly to be the description for that combo box entry (the one selected).

My UI is mostly contained within a Glade file. Currently, the UI is functional but changing between combo box entries does nothing to the textview.

EDIT: I removed the posting of my code because it's too long and maybe it was throwing people off. Apologies. I can post things at request. Thanks.